# How to quickly select multiple tiles in Windows 8 apps?

Tags: windows-8

I would like to select multiple songs for the music app to play. The files are presented as tiles. Is there any sort of multi-select, other than brute force click'm all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select multiple tiles by using the right mouse button:

1. **Right-click** the first song
2. hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and **right-click** the last song.

This works not only in Music, but in many other applications, e.g. in SkyDrive. Also, you can replace right-click with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-left-click, so to select songs this way you would:

1. Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and **left-click** the first song
2. Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and **left-click** the last song.

Comment: Easy, peasy. Thanks. Not the most intuitive solution. I don't understand why the left click doesn't do the same..

Comment: I think left click means *choose* (perform a default action on an element), while right click means *select*. Note that you can also click the left mouse button while holding Ctrl to achieve the same effect.

Comment: I think you meant Shift , not `Ctrl`.. but, yea. Left click works too, in cases where the default action is selection.

Comment: No, I meant Ctrl :) You can Ctrl-left-click the first song, then Ctrl-Shift-left-click the last song. Try it :)

Comment: Oh, ok. Your comment suggested otherwise ;)