# How to quickly select multiple tiles in Windows 8 start screen?

Tags: windows-8, start-screen

after installing an application there are *lots* of new tiles appeared at my Windows 8 start screen.

I want to remove them, but currently I only can right-click on them one by one and after selecting all press `Unpin from start` on the app bar.

Is there a faster way to select multiple tiles on start screen, similar to what is described for [Store apps](https://superuser.com/questions/497327/how-to-quickly-select-multiple-tiles-in-windows-8-apps)?

Comment: I would wait until Windows 8.1 is released to see if any of changes help.  I am pretty sure there is a folder that handles this behavior that you could open and navigate to and delete the files by hand ( although the current method is much safer ).

Comment: select 1 tile and when doing a right click you should see an option, "go to target". Here delete all links you don't need.

Comment: sorry, but right-clicking on tile give me only "Unpin", "Uninstall", "Smaller/Larger" and "Turn live tile on/off" on the appbar, no "Go to target". Where could I find such a command?